# Getting this error when trying to create new notebook

Tags: python-3.x, windows, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

**Unexpected error while saving file: Untitled.ipynb attempt to write a readonly database**

> I am using a windows10 machine, initially all it was working fine but
>   after upgrading python3(32-bit) to python3(64-bit)) and changing
>   python versions for couple of times, it is giving the weird error as
>   mentioned,i have looked many answers saying the access issue, tried
>   that too but nothing works for me.

i have completely removed the jupyter-notebook and again install it , but it doesn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

give proper permission or change owner for jupyter directory

```
sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu jupyter/
```